# SQL Statment with OR and AND < 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select rows that have columns with incomplete data. In this case, incomplete columns have a value less than 1. I'm trying to find rows that have at least one incomplete column, but I'm not sure how to combine this into a SQL statement. Here's what I've been trying unsuccessfully:

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM 
  eval 
WHERE 
  (month = :month) and (uid=:uid) 
OR (rotation < 1) 
OR (mr < 1) 
OR (nc < 1) 
OR (clinic_days < 1) 
OR (clinic_pts < 1) 
OR (mksap < 1)
```

This statement is returning multiple rows of data so the semantics must be incorrect. I get the same thing without the parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL `AND` takes precedence over `OR` in the same way as multiplication takes precedence over addition, so you need to use parentheses to force the precedence that you want:

```
SELECT id
FROM eval
WHERE (month = :month)
   AND 
       (uid=:uid)
   AND (
       (rotation < 1)
    OR (mr < 1)
    OR (nc < 1)
    OR (clinic_days < 1)
    OR (clinic_pts < 1)
    OR (mksap < 1)
    )
```

Your original statement will take the long chain of `OR`s, and return everything matched by any of its individual condition, along with the row that has the desire `:uid` and `:month`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the logic.  I think you want an `and` before the `or`, along with parentheses:

```
SELECT id
FROM eval
WHERE (month = :month) and (uid=:uid) AND
      ( (rotation < 1) OR (mr < 1) OR (nc < 1) OR (clinic_days < 1) OR
         (clinic_pts < 1) OR (mksap < 1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT id 
FROM eval 
WHERE (month = :month) 
and (uid=:uid) 
And( 
  (rotation < 1) 
   OR (mr < 1) 
   OR (nc < 1) 
   OR (clinic_days < 1)
   OR (clinic_pts < 1) 
   OR (mksap <1) 

)
```